# jQuery Regex Selector Plugin not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, jquery-plugins

Question. I've tried to add this old [jQuery Regex Selector](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) plugin but it doesn't seem to give me back the right tag. At least, it says undefined when I try to return any info on it. I hope to use this someday for a game so I can select dynamic tags and things like all the foreground elements.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var elm = $('img:regex(data:extension, png)');
    elm.each(function() { alert($(this).attr('alt')); });
});
```

But all I get back is `undefined` when I alert the `elm` I get back `[object Object]`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/2YCyU/)

Comment: `elm.prop("src")`? It's a jQuery collection of images, not a single DOM element!

Comment: It will return the same. Same for `attr()` already tried. That is true it should be a collection.

Comment: Looks like faulty logic in the expression, I changed it -> http://jsfiddle.net/2YCyU/9/

Comment: That does work but does not even use the expression he provides for getting .PNG images `$('img:regex(data:extension, png|jpg)');` [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/)

Comment: That's because in the expression it's turned into `$(element).data('extension')` which returns nothing in your case ?

Comment: There are much easier ways to just check the source, if that's all you're doing

Comment: It's going to be used for a grand amount of processing of DOM elements dynamically added and IDs always changing as movement happens with characters. Which is why I wanted to delegate my tags with regex to minimize code.

Comment: Not to mention it wouldn't be easier if I'm redoing the same code over and over again thousands of times when there is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you linked to: (emphasis mine)

Additionally it allows you to query data strings **added to elements via jQuery’s ‘data’ method:**

```
// Add data property to all images (just an example);
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).data('extension', $(this)[0].src.match(/\.(.{1,4})$/)[1]);
});

// Select all images with PNG or JPG extensions:
$('img:regex(data:extension, png|jpg)');
```

You would need to run both parts of that code, not just the second part. Your image in your example does not have a data attribute.

--EDIT--

Also, you don't need regex to get this functionality, just do this:

```
var elm = $('img[src$=png]');
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YfLG4/)

Comment: That makes sense. Though I thought it'd be based on the actual src and not user input, as that's not reliable to the source. :\ Your method remedies that though. :)

Comment: This is not it's only use as the commenting indicates. Ids will be dynamic, carrying character positions, states, map migrating, etc, etc.

Comment: If you plan your formatting for your ids well, you could get a long way with builtin selectors like attribute-contains `$('[id*=value]')`

Comment: I wouldn't be able to check multiple conditions without multiple lines of code though. Like if is this username, and is in this area of map, and is NOT active, and is NOT migrating, and is NOT casting, etc etc. Good point though, I already knew about all these. But the engine is already pushing 10,000 lines of code. I'm trying to trim it down.

Comment: The longest ID I've seen it create was over 2000 characters. That's a lot of `$('[id*=value]')` tests.

Comment: What on earth are you creating that would ever use an id that long. I have to believe there's a better model for your application than storing state in DOM ids

Comment: I was using localStorage but it would lag out to the fullest compared to DOM ids or a vast array in the script. ANd on my laptop, it would crash.

Comment: I'd point you to something like [`d3.js`](http://d3js.org/) that will let you bind data to DOM elements without making you parse their IDs all the time looking for data.

Comment: Do you have another suggestion? I was thinking of just going the JSON route and MySQL and PHP but then I'd need a reliable host besides my home servers. with only 200gb monthly transfer before I'm capped.

Comment: Ok, wow, that seems to have a lot of what I need built in! I may not even need to write a engine from scratch... little bit of a let down considering what I've managed so far on my own. :( But this is amazing. Damn you deserve an award. Lol